# Multiple SUM commands

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to sum a column in my table, the problem being there are multiple sums that need to be done.

So for instance there may be 40 records with an ID of 1 and a point value of 20,  And then it will change to a new person with an ID of 2 and a point value of 20.  If that makes sense.

How I want to do the query, but it doesn't work is like this:

```
SELECT SUM(Value) 
FROM Points WHERE RegNum IN('','','')
```

And then I would like it to show up just like a normal SUM command would, with the total summed up, but with a line for each ID.   I have looked over other questions about SUM commands and just can't quite apply it to my situation.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It won't fix your problem, but you should always GROUP BY when using aggregate functions.

Comment: @Iracicot In general using aggregate functions without specifying `GROUP BY` clause is absolutely OK in SQL. Just not in this case.

Comment: @peterm In general it's not what you want.

Comment: @Jack And why is that? Sometimes I want to group sometimes I don't. It depends on what I'm trying to get. What is your point?

Comment: @peterm My point is that one should first examine whether there's any logical column to group by before omitting it.

Comment: @Jack With that phrasing I can totally agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need to use a `GROUP BY` in your case. Try

```
SELECT RegNum, SUM(Value) total
  FROM Points 
 WHERE RegNum IN(1, 2, 3)
 GROUP BY RegNum
```

Sample output:

```
| REGNUM | TOTAL |
------------------
|      1 |    17 |
|      2 |     9 |
|      3 |     1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bf7a/2)** demo

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  SELECT RegNum, SUM(Value) as TotalRegNum
  From Points 
  WHERE RegNum IN('1','2','3')
  GROUP BY RegNum
```